# How many review audits did I fail?

Tags: feature-request, support, review-audits

I have been looking around for a while now, but I can't see anywhere how many audits I have failed.

Is this purposely not being exposed to users?

Where can I see some history of the audits I have failed?

Is there a raw number per category?

Comment: shall we put a feature-request then?

Answer (score 6):

I don't know anywhere in the UI where this is exposed as a raw number or percentage.

As far as I know, you have to figure it out yourself. You can do that by looking at your recent activity in your profile. [Filter by "reviews"](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2140173/mehow?tab=activity&sort=reviews), and click through the items looking for review audits. Whether you passed or failed is clearly indicated at the top of the results page.

For example, you passed [this suggested edit audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2702927), and passed [this first posts review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/2652665).

Comment: **Note:** Only failed review audits from Close Votes, Reopen Votes, and Suggested Edits appear in your review activity. For some reason failed audits from Low Quality Posts, Late Answers, and First Posts do not.

Comment: @animuson: This might have something to do with negative audits for those queues having already been deleted, whereas negative audits for other queues have the source post still exist.