# Red tags in headings is hurting my eyes

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design, mobile-web

When browsing through Meta, I ran across [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266868/350567) by Shog:

> ```
> ## [meta-tag:status-completed]
> ```
>
> [image]

I thought I was drunk, but immediately denied that guess. So I went on and made a [test](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306259/350567):

> [image]

It's really hurting. Can we fix that, possibly by removing the white "shadow" under texts in headings? Since in most places of SE the background is white (the only exception I can think of is A51), that white "shadow" is very likely invisible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for reporting. Tags inherited text-shadow from some parent elements. It should now be fixed.