# Ability for users without the moderator tools privilege to see deleted posts they reviewed doesn't work for "Share feedback" reviews

Tags: bug, review, deleted-posts

In the review queue history, when you open a review task you performed, [you can always see the content of the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228955/allow-all-reviewers-to-see-deleted-posts-they-reviewed), even if that post is now deleted and you don't have the [privilege to view deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools):

[image]

However, if you chose "Share feedback" in the First Questions and First Answers review queue, the deleted post is not visible; all it says is *question not found* or *answer not found*:

[image]

Comment: Does it happen when just clicking the "Share feedback", or after actually posting the comment?

Comment: It happens after posting the comment (well, then you go to the next review task - the bug is apparent when you go back, or use the review queue history to go to an old item)

Comment: I still can't see the whole picture. You can't post comments when the post is deleted. You say review skip this check? Or are you doing it as a moderator?

Comment: The post is deleted after the review, and I just want to check what exactly I reviewed. (It's unlikely to occur by navigating back in your browser, unless the deletion is really soon after the review.)

Comment: And what happens if you post ordinary comment, not via the review? Is it still giving the "not found" when viewing the review item?

Comment: The first screenshot is from where I flagged the answer and chose "Other action". I expect it'll be the same if I leave a comment and chose "Other action". I checked some other reviews I did and even when choosing "Looks OK" you can see the deleted post's content.

Comment: Most likely cause is that the system which allows for this checks for specific review task result types, and it wasn't updated to add the new one for "Share feedback".