# Why can a >1K user not see up and down votes on deleted questions and answers accessible to them from the history of a review queue?

Tags: support, review, voting

I was recently going through the history of my First Questions and Triage review queues to see how I am doing. I clicked on "Looks OK" of a deleted question which took me to the screen with the question (even though my reputation is less than 10K) and I saw it had a positive score of 2.

I clicked on the 2 to see whether the question had any down votes and a small spinning wheel appeared and the score did not turn into the up/down votes (I am >1K on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/))

[image]

So, I clicked on the show activity button below the vote buttons and that took me to the "Page not found" page.

There appears to be no way for me to find out what the voting was on this question.

Of course, I understand I should not normally see other people's deleted posts, but it is possible to access other people's deleted posts from the history of a review queue, so why can I not see the up and down votes of a deleted post from the history of a review queue?

Comment: Aren't there other parts of the deleted review which don't work either? (Like showing all the comments when they're collapsed.)

Comment: @Laurel I went through anything I could find to click on a deleted post and found the following: Clicking on a comment gives the popup: "Comments on deleted questions cannot be upvoted". Clicking on a comment flag displays the "Why are you flagging this comment" dialog which seems to work as normal, however I have not tested it by flagging anything. Instead of "Add a comment" appears the message "Comments disabled on deleted / locked posts / reviews". Clicking on the collapse message "Show 2 more comments" gives the popup: "This post has been deleted and its comments are no longer available"

Comment: @Laurel And some more: Clicking on a vote button gives the popup: "This post has been deleted; deleted posts can't be voted on". Clicking on "edited Nov ...." gives "Page not found". Clicking on share gives the popup "Share a link to this question ..." Clicking on Follow lets me follow the post (changing the button to "Following" and indeed the post is in my follows list) however on refresh the Following button on the post reverts to Follow. So I have a deleted question in my follow list, but the deleted post does not display "Following".

Comment: Well, [blame Oded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266868/152859). ;)

Comment: The answer to this is likely either "we didn't think of that possibility" or that it's just easier/better for the permissions on the endpoint to not include the additional database accesses needed to determine if a user can see the deleted post as a result of having reviewed it. IIRC, access to that endpoint is currently something like: does the user have permission to see deleted posts || is the user the post owner || is post a question on which the user has an answer. Adding the check for being able to see the deleted post due to having reviewed it would require additional database accesses.

Comment: Yeah, I think some of that would be helpful to have, but obviously not the ability to leave comments on deleted posts (and similar).